# Regex in Swift gives different result

Tags: swift, regex, iphone, validation

I am using this regex in my Swift,

```
    let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "^[a-zA-Zåçêëèïîìæôöòûùÿáíóúñ]+(?:[-' ][a-zA-Zåçêëèïîìæôöòûùÿáíóúñ]+)*$")
    let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: newValue.utf16.count)
    
    if regex.firstMatch(in: value, options: [], range: range) == nil {
        print("Not passed")
    } { 
        print("Passed") 
    }
```

but it gives different result from the website https://regex101.com/r/EXWsK1/2,
what am i doing wrong here?

In my swift code, it should accept the aposthropes character such as Le'brahm, O'Niel, etc like the example on the website, but it does not.

Comment: Exactly what are you trying to do, maybe this could be better solved with [CharacterSet](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/characterset) instead?

Comment: No character set will help here since the the string must meet a *sequence* of specific *patterns*, not just a sequence of specific chars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the curly single quotation marks, `‘’`, to the pattern:

```swift
pattern: "^[a-zA-Zåçêëèïîìæôöòûùÿáíóúñ]+(?:[-'‘’ ][a-zA-Zåçêëèïîìæôöòûùÿáíóúñ]+)*$"
```

The straight quotation marks are replaced with curly ones by default.